# How can I increase the maximum number of lines ("window height") in a Qt console application?

Tags: qt, console

I'm writing a quick&dirty number crunching test, using a Qt console application.

It prints several thousand lines, but the number of lines displayed in the console seems to be limited to about 300. This means that at the end I can no longer scroll back to the beginning of my printout.

How can I raise this limit? I found nothing in the project settings.

Or is it completely impossible, as the console window is controlled solely by my operating system?
It's important for me to launch the program directly from Qt creator, so a solution where I use a batch script or similar trick to run my program is not preferable.

Does a solution even exist, or am I forced to switch to a Qt GUI application where I create my own console out of a QTextEdit widget?

Comment: What is your target OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of lines displayed and the number of lines in the buffer is a property of the operating system. You can change this. How to do this depends on your OS.

Comment: For Windows that's basically HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\ScreenBufferSize in the registry. I was hoping I can do something with my project or program itself, but for a rarely used tool, I guess I'll have to contend with this.